# Javascript sort array of strings by number and then letter

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, compare

With this array of objects:

```
[
{a: "1M"},
{a: "10D"},
{a: "1D"},
{a: "6Y"},
{a: "3D"}
]
```

how to sort this array to get this result:

```
[
"1D",
"3D",
"10D",
"1M",
"6Y"
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: try splitting each value into number and string.

Comment: I have tried to use localeCompare, passing a custom function to the sort method but I hav enot gotten the desired result

Comment: If you're sorting by number and then letter, wouldn't your desired array be 1D, 1M, 3D, 6Y, 10D? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @reastere its suggested that you include what you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for getting a factor for the given unit and sort by value.

```js
const
    getValue = s => ({ D: 1, M: 30, Y: 365 })[s.slice(-1)] * s.slice(0, -1),
    array = [{ a: "1M" }, { a: "10D" }, { a: "1D" }, { a: "6Y" }, { a: "3D" }],
    result = array
        .map(({ a }) => a)
        .sort((a, b) => getValue(a) - getValue(b));

console.log(result);
```

Sorting by alphabet

```js
const
    array = [{ a: "1M" }, { a: "10D" }, { a: "1D" }, { a: "6Y" }, { a: "3D" }],
    result = array
        .map(({ a }) => a)
        .sort((a, b) =>
            a.slice(-1).localeCompare(b.slice(-1)) ||
            a.slice(0, -1) - b.slice(0, -1)
    );

console.log(result);
```